# How do I get the app.json `slug` value from the app?

Tags: javascript, expo

Is there a way for me to log the [slug](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v46.0.0/config/app/#slug) in the console on an EAS built application?
I can't find it even if I do [`JSON.stringify(Constants)`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/constants/#easconfig)

Answer (score 0):

In the end it appears to be marked as `@anonymous/${slug}` which prevents me from sending notifications using Expo.